# Supercooling biology

Tags: science-based, creature-design, xenobiology, anatomy

I want a chemical reaction that could take place in an organism that can super cool the air within that organism. In nature, there are exothermic reactions that release heat. What is a chemical reaction within an organism that allows it to super cool air in its body? What is the structure made of that allows it to withstand this chemical reaction?

Comment: If you do this, the organism might be able to make a cold pocket (like a refrigerator), but would be producing vast amounts of waste heat in the process (although you could maybe make the heating happen earlier). Is this acceptable? It would probably be better of with some kind of biological compressor system. What is the biological function of such a system?

Comment: There is no chemical reaction which can make something **super**cool. There are some physical or chemical processes which can [cool things down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothermic_process), such as dissolving [ammonium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate) in water -- this is used for example in some [instant cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_pack) packs. In other words, the question must clarify how super should the supercooling be.

Comment: Hi i have a doubt mr.DWKraus how could a organism make cold pocket ? what is an biological compresser means what is meaning of that and how could that work please tell this an answer to this question and may be heat produced could be used to warm the creature when it super cool air by a structure that channel stored heat (how this could gappen?can you tell)

Comment: Hi Alexp super cooled means a strong enough chemical reaction which cooled air interact with hot air around the atmosphere to make mini storm beam

Answer (score 2):

### Thermoacoustic refrigeration

[Sound can be used to create temperature differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoacoustics).  It is actually possible to [do this as a science project](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Publications/ThermoDemo.pdf).  *(I feel guilty for posting the second link, as I have just condemned one or more families to weeks of abyssal torment at the hands of their budding ... genius, for no more reason than Downtown Julie spoiled Citizen Kane, but what can I say?  The bit got between my teeth!)*  Frost dragons are loud, and I wouldn't want to have one in my kitchen, but who is going to argue with it?  Vocal cords to replace the speaker in the diagram from the second link, a resonating cavity with the right characteristics, and you should be good to go.

But it's just cooling, not *supercooling*.  Fish are super cool because they have proteins that interact with tiny ice crystals to keep them from growing inside their cells - but that's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Chemical reactions only happen when there is a decrease in energy ie they emit energy (exothermic) or if there is an increase in entropy. Endothermic reaction occur when the increase in entropy outweighs the increase in energy.

To have a **Chemical** reaction producing a change in temperature to cool a pocket to temps of ~100K would be borderline impossible, especially in a creature producing it over ~30 seconds.

But if you are just after a cold air pocket, then what your creature could have a piston type chamber that uses muscle to contract it, while not letting any air out this heats the gas inside, same effect is used in [fire pistons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_piston). When the higher pressure gas is released from the chamber it cools the surrounding environment this might give you the colder temperatures you need

hopefully that helps