# Natural cryogenic substance

Tags: creature-design, dragons, ice

I'm researching a way a dragon could expel a substance that freezes things it comes in contact with. I've seen two posts here on the WBSE with this theme, but both said about the animal **evolving** to have this feature and I think this might limit a little bit on how this could happen. Also, I've seen responses suggesting using liquid nitrogen, but liquid nitrogen doesn't freeze a person, if it does, it takes a long time, you can't use it as a weapon in battle.

Now the question: **could an animal expel a substance that freezes the things it touches and is effective in battle?**

- My dragon he is created, did not arise from evolution;
- It's a carnivore, I don't know if that matters, but it's there in case you need to know;
- The substance will be expelled together with the water, so if the water freezes it may incapacitate the target, even a little, or create ice blocks("hail") that have fallen on those below;
- The substance cannot be toxic, as the animal will be mounted and it will not be good if the rider ends up intoxicating nearby allies;
- The substance has to be easy to make and store, not something that would depend on super machinery to manufacture and store.

Comment: And here I thought you wanted a creature that would shit ice cubes! Alas...

Comment: Does it have to be water ice, other wise you could use [hot ice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzHiVGeevZE)

Comment: You might find this reference useful. https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/stem-in-context/cold-pack-a-chilly-example-endothermic-reaction

Comment: Don't knock liquid nitrogen. It's dangerous stuff to "play" with, and it can also asphyxiate https://ehs.research.uiowa.edu/liquid-nitrogen-handling. As a warmer alternative, dry ice shards cause physical damage + cold burns

Comment: I think you'll need to drop the requirement of this fast-freezing of a human. this is simply not possible in a battle setting. A (best-case) unarmored human with 100kg water content @35degC needs to have (100*333 + 100*4*35)kJ, so about 47MJ of heat removed before being all ice. To do that in 10 seconds  5MW would need to leave the human during that time. that is not feasible, if you do not have the human as a very thin paste on a large surface, and in that case, whats the point in freezing them.... ?

Comment: You might also want to research the Leidenfrost effect if you really want that  'less than 10 seconds' bit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect

Comment: I know the creature is alive, hence the non-toxicity requirement, but is it in any way mechanical or cybernetic?(it being created sparked this curiosity)

Comment: No, it's a 100% organic creature.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable solution seems to be large quantities of liquid propane dumped onto the target.

- Propane can be maintained liquid [at about 10atm](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/propane-d_1423.html) at 20-30C.
- Has a high vapor pressure - 8 atm at 20C, so any liquid propane will vaporize as fast as it can.
- Each kg of liquid propane will need 428kJ to evaporate (latent heat of evaporation) and will freeze about 0.2kg of water (latent heat of fusion for water: 2,260kJ/kg).

To completely freeze an 80kg human with 70% water, one will need to douse the human with about 250kg of liquid propane (and better keep it thermally isolated from the environment, so that the heat is extracted from the human. I suggest putting it into a barrel, isolated by some blankets).
At about 580 kg/m^3, it means a wee bit under half a cubic meter of liquid propane.

Do I need to mention one should avoid naked flame or sparks during the freezing process?

---

Of course, you can try other liquids with a high vapor pressure, like liquid carbon dioxide, nitrogen or helium, but the storage is gonna be a harder problem. Avoid liquid ammonia, though, its dissolution in water is exothermic.

---

Are you sure you want a tanker filled with cryo liquids as an animal?

Comment: Ammonia IS a very good refrigerant, https://www.goodway.com/hvac-blog/2009/08/ammonia-as-a-refrigerant-pros-and-cons/ if you organism can use an internal compressor system. then is can be exhaled as poison gas, and it's flammable, so it could produce fire. In AD&D terms, that's the bulk (white, green, red) of dragon breath. Cold is still the hardest to justify. Good answer, BTW.

Comment: @DWKraus I though about it, but it's too chemically active (especially against proteins) and a bit towards corrosive when you mix it with water (which ammonia simply loves to do). Dousing the victim in ammonia may resemble more of a chemical attack than a cryo one.

Comment: This is supposed to be a breath weapon, so maybe destructive isn't so bad. The water expelled could be super-cooled internally, then expand on exhalation, freezing on  contact. The ammonia never leaves the beast or touches the water. Oh, I almost forgot "Acid" breath, as ammonia would give you the (black) corrosive breath weapon as well! I'm seeing a common ammonia-utilizing ancestor to all evil dragon types. Plus ammonia is a lifting gas, so maybe used in dragon flight...

Comment: That dragon better be made of non-biological substances, at least on the part that filters and liquefies ammonia. And don't try supercooled water [if you intend to have a moving dragon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9N-Y2CyYhM). Actually, you may want to think of a jet formation that uses teleportation, so that the supercooled water molecules don't get opportunities to [change their mind and huddle together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHJ3rjqEFmA)

Comment: And how would the animal get the propane?

Comment: @WizardKing like any cryogenic substance, from a specialized store. That's why my final question at the end of the answer. Look, there's no biological arrangement to do what you asked for, you'll need to handwave like crazy. Since you already need to handwave, feel free to imagine ways of acquiring those substances - maybe the dragon has access to a crack in a cave above deep coal mine in fire and evolved some way of filtering and retaining propane while letting the other gaseous products escape. Or use compressed carbon dioxide - a little bit higher pressure needed, but you accepted 10 atm...

Comment: While there might be easier substances than Propane, my main problem with this is that the dragon needs to expel 250kg of *something* per adversary, that is not viable

Comment: @bukwyrm hey, you should be [happy with that](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fluids-evaporation-latent-heat-d_147.html)! Look, liquid nitrogen is less than half of that (199kJ/kg) so you'll need 500kg for the same. Liquid ammonia would be about 2.5 better and only require to dump 100kg, but you ain't gonna store liquid ammonia in anything of biological nature, even more a living one.

Comment: @
Wizard King "And how would the animal get the propane?} - a lot of farts.

Comment: This doesn't require the propane to be particularly pure; naturally produced propane could include significant admixture of butane and small percentages of ethane and pentane and still work well for this kind of (ab)use.

Comment: It looks like you used the latent heat of *vaporization* for water, which is nearly an order of magnitude higher than the latent heat of fusion! The latent heat of fusion is only 334kJ/kg - 1kg of evaporating propane can freeze 1.4kg of water at 0 degrees C. It'll condense only 0.2kg of steam at 100 degrees C. Once you account the additional 130ish kJ/kg to go from body temperature to freezing, liquid propane can freeze a man at nearly a 1:1 mass ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a chemical to produce the ice, you could have a chamber full of [superchilled water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling). This is water cooled below it freezing point but it doesn't have a nucleation site to freeze from so it stays as a liquid, but as soon as it hits something that is can crystallise around (most thing work, it is far harder to stop it freezing) it starts to freeze.
[image]

To Stop it freezing in you dragon the chamber it is stored in would have to be **very** smooth, possible a grown protein structure. To cool the water you might be able to use a system described in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/215592/79015)

hopefully that helps

Comment: And make sure your dragon sits perfectly still until the attack, moderate agitation may cause a sudden increase in the superchilled water volume.

Comment: Your dragon might keep the water compressed, allowing the water to stay liquid, then it gets cold as it expands.

Comment: @DWKraus that is a *Cool* idea

Comment: @DWKraus You know how water is practically uncompressible and that ice has 10% more volume. The problem... umm... boils down to what pressure one will need to maintain to compress water by 10% and if, at that pressure, you won't still get some sort of the [19 possible crystalline structures of ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice#Phases). But all is not lost, it may  actually work if you dissolve in the water a good amount of suspension of belief ;)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi looking at the phase diagram for water, i think the pressure would have to be ~1000 atmospheres to have a significate affect on the freezing temperature. So while possible I don't think it is practical.

Comment: Doh, the substance to be dissolved for this to work is "suspension of *disbelief*".

Comment: the ice in the gif looks kinda soggy - is there a way to have this become a solid block of ice? I love the general idea, but this soft-ice will not really hinder any enemy. Being able to encase them in solid ice though...  Would some supercooled non-water crystals in the superccoled water help? Idea being to have the crystal go liquid on impact, drawing further heat from the forming ice, solidifying it... or something?

Comment: @bukwyrm I think that as it crystallises over a few seconds then the first crystal are thinner shards, and you have a bit of a slush. But as the rest of the water crystallises, then it freezes together. I think there is also a dependency on how cold the water was to start with, if it wasn't to cold you get a slush, there is a solider looking chunk at the end of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fot3m7kyLn4 )

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Good point, I was actually thinking about soda when I said that, but that is because the CO2 depresses the freezing point, and is released when the pressure is released. But something similar could work. Natural carbonation?

Comment: @DWKraus I'd borrow the carbonite tech. I mean, look, it worked perfectly on Harrison Ford. Would it make it then natural carbonition?

Answer (score 0):

I know Bombardier beetles expel 2 chemicals to create a hot explosion. A quick google search produced [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.macromol.8b00239)

> We show that liquid polyoxacyclobutane −[CH2–CH2–CH2–O]n– when mixed
> with water at room temperature precipitates solid cocrystals of the
> polymer and water. Cocrystals can also be formed by simply exposing
> the liquid polymer to saturated humidity. This appears to be the only
> known example of nonreacting liquids combining to form a solid
> cocrystal, also known as a clatherate, at room temperature. At high
> temperatures, the same polymer–water mixtures phase separate into two
> coexisting liquid phases. This combination of cocrystal formation and
> LCST-type liquid–liquid equilibrium gives rise to an unusual, possibly
> unique, type of phase diagram.

Comment: Their spray does not produce an explosion, but the reaction is quite exothermic.